# Trying to align text under an image using flexbox

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

I am trying to align a `p` tag underneath an image. Should be simple but I've messed around with this for a bit and must not be seeing something. Here is my code:

```css
.project {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
.project1 {
  height: 10rem;
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid rgba(52, 73, 94, 1);
}
.project1info {
  background: rgba(52, 73, 94, 1);
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <h1 class="subHead">Some Projects I Have Worked On</h1>
  <h2 class="description"></h2>
</div>
<div class="project">
  <a href="https://hidden-brook-12046.herokuapp.com/">
    <img class="project1" src="./images/featuring.png" alt="" />
  </a>
  <p class="project1info">
    Featuring allows a user to search a musical artist and view a list of collaboraters they have worked with.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row`. This means that the children of a flex container will align horizontally.

If you want them to stack vertically, override the default with `flex-direction: column`.

```
.project {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* NEW */
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
```

If, for whatever reason, you need to keep the container with `flex-direction: row`, then you can add `flex-wrap: wrap` and give the first flex item a width of 100%. This will force the second flex item to wrap to the next line.

```
.project {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* NEW */
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
.project > a {
  flex: 0 0 100%;  /* NEW */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7mj9dfq/1/)

```
.project {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

use `flex-direction: column;`